# std::vector parent's virtual method getting called instead of child

Tags: c++

I'd like to have a Vector of a class with a virtual method which the child can override. But I can't place purely virtual classes in a vector so I have an inherited class which I called Parent to be placed in the vector; However when I push an item into the Vector itself, I'm pushing an instance of Child not Parent. But when I call it's virtual method, the parent's method gets called instead of the child's method?
I'm sorry if that's confusing to explain but here's the example code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
class ParentAbstract
{
public:
    virtual void Test() = 0;
};
class Parent : public ParentAbstract
{
public:
    Parent()
    {
        
    }
    virtual void Test()
    {
        std::cout << "parent" << std::endl;
    }
};
class Child : public Parent
{
    using Parent::Parent;
public:
    virtual void Test()
    {
        std::cout << "child" << std::endl;
    }
};

 int main()
{
     std::vector<Parent> v;
     v.push_back(Child());
     v.at(0).Test();
}
```

In this example there's a pure virtual class called ParentAbstract. A second class called Parent which inherits and overrides the Test method, a third class called Child which inherits Parent and overrides the Test method. My Vector is of type Parent because I can't make it of type ParentAbstract.. But in my main method when I do v.push_back, I try to create a child instance instead of the parent instance. Which I assume should end up calling the Child's Test method. But that doesn't happen. The Parent's Test method is called instead..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ Overridden method not getting called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444025/c-overridden-method-not-getting-called) - s. also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing

Comment: Try this - `std::vector<Parent *> v; Child x; v.push_back(&x); v.at(0)->Test();`. Once you get the expected behavior you will be wondering and then you would like to read about object slicing in `C++`.

Comment: Yes thank you both, that does answer the question. I wasn't aware that "slicing" happens if you store a copy. But I'm confused. @H.S.Isn't that pushing an address of a local variable? Which is undefined behavior?

Comment: @Ray Thank you for that. I suppose I have to use a shared_ptr or a pointer that isn't local?

Comment: @Kayla No it's not, as long as pointer is valid. Moreover, in my sample code, address of a local object variable has been copied to vector where both object and vector are declared/defined in one function which is `main()`. Of course, it was just to demonstrate you, where you are making mistake in understanding the concept of `virtual` in `C++`.

Comment: @H.S. I understand , thank you. So the solution is, I have to store a pointer. And that pointer has to be valid... unfortunately I really didn't want to store pointers and store copies instead..

Comment: @Kayla It depends on the lifetime you require for the elements and the vector. In your code above, H.S.'s solution is sufficient since the vector and elements are both valid only on the stack of `main()`, otherwise you will need to use (smart) pointers and put the objects on the heap (and manage the lifetime explicitly with `new` and `delete` in case of raw pointers).

Comment: Unfortunately, c++ achieve polymorphism by pointers. Another way: use a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Parent>>`. Also don't forget to make base destructor virtual or you'll leak memory

Comment: @LouisGo That's understandable thank you. Realistically what I wanted is to make a copy of the container because I didn't want to effect the origina container..however if I use a pointer then I'm effecting the original data in the original container which defeats the purpose..

Comment: @Kayla Remember, polymorphism only work with pointer or reference and that too only with virtual methods.