# Why is virtual function not being called?

Tags: c++

```
//GUITEXT
class guitext : public entity {
public:
    guitext(graphics *gfx, std::string _text, float _x, float _y, 
        float _size, float timeToLive);
    bool update(float deltaTime, gameworld *world);
    void draw(graphics *gfx);
};

void guitext::draw(graphics *gfx) { printf("draw"); }

//ENTITY

class entity {
public:
    virtual bool update(float deltaTime, gameworld *world) 
        { return false; }
    virtual void draw(graphics *gfx) { }
};

//GAMEWORLD

void gameworld::addEntity(entity e) { entitys.push_back(e); }

//MAIN 

for(int i = 0; i < (int)entitys.size(); i++) { entitys[i].draw(gfx); }
```

I have a vector in my gameworld class. When I add push a guitext entity to this vector I expect it to call the guitext::draw() function. But the base class function is being called. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ Overriding Methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230006/c-overriding-methods)

Comment: Comment on code: Rather than use the correct type you think casting away the problem `(int)entitys.size()` is a good idea! Learn **never** to use the C-Style cast operator and use the C++ case operators only when absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You made a vector of `entity`. Those objects *always* have type `entity`. If you want to invoke polymorphism, they need to be pointers or references. How can a vector of `entity` store a `guitext`? There's not enough space, it doesn't know how to destroy it, etc etc.

Comment: @Martin: Someone else already posted an answer with a link to slicing. I'm all for writing wonder answers, but I'm not gonna dupe.

Answer (score 4):

Was the vector declared as `vector<entity>`? Then only the base class part can be stored there, i.e. you lose polymorphism (which only works through pointer or reference in C++).

Comment: I believe that it only works through pointer or reference in any language, but that most languages have virtually exclusive GC references, like Java or C#.

Comment: Yes, under the hood, but C++ requires explicit syntax.

Answer (score 4):

What you've done is a bit concealed variant of [slicing.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

You should define `entitys` to contain pointers to `entity`. Slightly edited example derived from your code.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class entity 
{
public:
    virtual void draw() { }
};

class guitext : public entity 
{
public:
    void draw()
    {
        printf("draw");
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::vector<entity *> entitys;

    guitext g;

    entitys.push_back(&g); 

    for(int i = 0; i < (int)entitys.size(); i++) 
    { 
        entitys[i]->draw(); 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C++'s default entrypoint is int main, and there is no standard _TCHAR in C++. `stdafx.h` is some Microsoft-specific extension.

Comment: Yes, This is a compilable and runnable example (on Visual Studio) to illustrate the point.

Answer (score 0):

You're storing `Entity`s, not pointers to objects of varying derived types of `Entity`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, in your case it's not good idea to pass arguments by value, i suppose there will be very big quantity of objects that need to be redrawed. Better, by const reference, since functon doesn't change state of passed object inside.